# Marshalling jSON big ints turn into floats to the power

Tags: json, types, go, marshalling

I have this piece of data:

```
productID, err := products.Insert(map[string]interface{}{
    "Properties": map[string]interface{}{
        strconv.Itoa(propertyNameID): map[string]string{
            "en": "Jeans Jersey",
            "nl": "Broek Jersey",
        },
        strconv.Itoa(propertyColorID): propertyOptionRedID,
    },
    "Type":        productTypeID,
    "Propertyset": propertysetID,
    "Active":      true,
    "EAN13":       "1234567890123"})
```

All the `***ID` variables are of type `int`. Sadly when I do a normal marshal:

```
{  
    "Active":true,
    "EAN13":"1234567890123",
    "Properties":{  
        "2286408386526632249":{  
            "en":"Jeans Jersey",
            "nl":"Broek Jersey"
        },
        "4750062295175300168":7.908474319828591e+18
    },
    "Propertyset":8.882218269088507e+18,
    "Type":7.185126253999425e+18
}
```

... the some ints are transformed into `float` type to the power.

The `Itoa` are still just some tests tho, because the marshaller can't do `map[int]interface{}` (lists with index-values as integers). I just don't understand why the `int` values get changed to their "display"-value, instead of their pure value.

**Update:** I tried "Properties" with `map[string]int` and just one entry. Still the same result :(

Comment: I can't confirm right now.. but from memory, the marshaller uses `float64` for all numbers in an interface by default. It will then call `String()` on it at some point resulting in the scientific/E notation you're seeing if the number is large enough.

Comment: Isn't that very strange? (long) numbers are probably the most common values in jSON files. Should I just `Itoa` all integers? :P That will probably decrease my performance terrible when the request load on my server becomes heavier.

Answer (score 3):

You can marshal an int64 as a string in json to avoid the conversion to a float64 by using the `string` tag

```
type T struct {
    Val int64 `json:"val,string"`
}
t := T{Val: math.MaxInt64}
j, _ := json.Marshal(t)
fmt.Println(string(j))
// {"val":"9223372036854775807"}
```